# Creating Polygons based on 2 XY points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, coordinates

I have an excel file with 2 x,y coordinates as columns. One set of coordinates is the top left vertex of a rectangle, the other set is the bottom right vertex of the rectangle.

Is there anyway to plot these coordinates and have Arcmap automatically draw rectangles connecting these vertexes? I've searched on here for the answer but kept getting hung up on some of the options. Preferably a solution without using arcpy.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your question to include details about what exactly you've tried, and where you get stuck.  What options are you "getting hung up on"?

Comment: a pair of 2 coordinates is a line not a polygon

Comment: @ziggy not if you treat them as an extent.

Comment: Not sure why this is on hold. Seems clear to me. Follow these steps: 1) add XY data from File menu. Then export data. (2) use the XY To Line geoprocessing tool to convert the XY Coordinates to a Line (3) Use the Line as input into the Minimum Bounding Geometry geoprocessing tool.  All of the geoprocessing tools are under Data Management Tools\Features

Comment: @Brad I suggest you post that as an answer

Comment: What license level is available? You can use @Brad 's solution with Advanced, but won't have access to the 'ENVELOPE' option with Basic/Standard.

Comment: @phloem this resource shows it as available with all versions: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm#L_

Comment: @Brad further up in that link you'll see (under Syntax > geometry_type) that `ENVELOPE` is only available under Advanced license

Comment: The tool is available, but the output geometry type is limited by license level.

Comment: @phloem wouldn't convex hull suffice for 2 vertices?

Comment: @Brad convex hull is also only available to Advanced, but regardless it would result in a line (or error) for only two points.

Comment: right, I misread

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Brad convert pairs of points to lines.

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("LINES", "EXTENT")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("LINES", "D:/Scratch/buffers.shp", "1 Meters")
```

Apply this field calculator expression on field Shape of buffers:

```
def toExtent(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax):
 LL=arcpy.Point(xmin,ymin)
 UL=arcpy.Point(xmin,ymax)
 UR=arcpy.Point(xmax,ymax)
 LR=arcpy.Point(xmax,ymin)
 array=arcpy.Array([LL,UL,UR,LR])
 polygon=arcpy.Polygon(array)
 return polygon
#------------------------
toExtent( !EXT_MIN_X!, !EXT_MIN_Y!, !EXT_MAX_X!, !EXT_MAX_Y! )
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know you prefer not to use arcpy, but I'm not sure how you can get around it with Basic/Standard license. After you've got your Excel spreadsheet into an ArcMap table view:

```
fc = 'my_table' # the table
fields = ['N_Lat','W_Lon','S_Lat','E_Lon'] # coordinate fields. Order is important.
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) # spatial reference. Assume WGS_1984.
out_recs = [] # placeholder
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields) as cursor: # loop through table
    for row in cursor:
        extent = arcpy.Extent(row[1],row[2],row[3],row[0]) # create extent object
        extent_poly = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([extent.upperLeft,extent.upperRight,extent.lowerRight,extent.lowerLeft]),sr) # create polygon from extent. Define spatial reference.
        out_recs.append(extent_poly) # add to polygon list
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(out_recs,r'in_memory\out_recs') # write to disk
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps (Advanced license only):

(1) From the File Menu\Add Data\Add XY Data
- Add your XY Data and export as feature class.

(2) Use this as input for the "XY To Line" geoprocessing tool

(3) Use the line as input into the Minimum Bounding Geometry geoprocessing tool.

All of the geoprocessing tools are under Data Management Tools\Features

Comment: (1) to be done twice

Comment: XY to Line will take a table/text/csv/etc. directly so you don't need to feature a feature class first.